# proving that $ab$ is a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

let $a,b \ge 2$ be integers, such that for every positive integer $n$, the expression :

$(a^n-1)(b^n-1)$ is a perfect square.
How to prove that $ab$ is a perfect square.

Comment: What about $a=1$, $b=2$?

Comment: Sorry ,$a$ and $b$ are greater than one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $[a^{3n}-1][b^{3n}-1]$ is a square and $[a^{n}-1][b^{n}-1]$ is a non-zero square, the quotient $[a^{2n}+a^n+1][b^{2n}+b^n+1]$ is also a square for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Suppose that $ab$ is not a square.  A consequence of quadratic reciprocity is that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $\left(\frac{ab}p\right) = \left(\frac{3}p\right)=-1$ (the density of such primes is at least $\tfrac14$).  Fix $p$ to be one such prime.

Now, exactly one of $a$ and $b$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$.  Choosing $n=(p-1)/2$, Euler's criterion shows that $a^{2n}+a^n+1$ is $3 \pmod p$ if $a$ is a residue and $1\pmod p$ if $a$ is a non-residue.  Therefore $[a^{2n}+a^n+1][b^{2n}+b^n+1] \equiv 3 \pmod p$, so it can't be a square.

This is a very nice problem, and I imagine that other quite different attacks are possible.  I'd like to know if there is a way to deduce the much stronger statement that $a = b$, since that seems like the only plausible way to make $[a^{n}-1][b^{n}-1]$ always a non-zero square.

Comment: how do you prove the existence of such prime $p$ ?

Comment: @user56777 That's fairly standard, but takes a bit of fiddling.  Reciprocity shows that if $q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_k$ are distinct primes, then you can independently prescribe each $(q_i/p)$ by choosing $p$ in the right congruence class.  Now choose $(3/p) = -1$ and (if needed) some other prime $q$ dividing $ab$ to have $(q/p)=-1$.

Comment: @ErickWong: How does that imply that $ab \equiv 3 \pmod p$?

Comment: @SandeepSilwal I never claimed $ab \equiv 3 \pmod p$, nor is it expected by the problem.  It appears you are confused about the meaning of the Legendre symbol: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol

Comment: This uses Dirichlet's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach using the LTE lemma.

Assume $(a^n-1)(b^n-1)$ is a perfect square for all $n\ge 1$ with $ab$ being a non perfect square. This means $$\left(\frac{ab}{p}\right)=-1$$ for some odd prime $p$.

Without lost of generality, assume $a$ is a quadratic residue and $b$ a quadratic nonresidue $\pmod p$. Now set $n=r=(p-1)/2$ using Euler's criterion we get $$p\mid a^{r}-1 \text{ and } p\mid b^{r}+1$$

We know $(a^r-1) (b^r-1)$ is a square so $$2\mid\nu_p((a^r-1) (b^r-1))=\nu_p(a^r-1)$$ because $p\not\mid b^r-1$ otherwise $p=2$ Now set $n=r p$ and note that $p \not\mid b^{rp}-1$ because $p\mid b^{pr}+1$ to get $$\nu_p((a^{rp}-1)(b^{rp}-1))=\nu_p(a^{r}-1)+\nu_p(p)=\nu_p(a^r-1)+1 $$ which is odd so it can't be divisible by $2$ hence the contradiction.

Comment: This argument can be generalized to see that for every odd prime $p$ (not sure whether $p=2$ still works similarly), and every $n \geq 1$, $p|a^n-1$ iff $p|b^n-1$.

Comment: Can we show $a=b$ using this method? @Aphelli

Comment: If you don’t mind heavy algebraic number theory, I give an argument on this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4264555/if-mathrmord-pb-mid-mathrmord-pa-for-all-sufficiently-large-prime-p . But this problem is the N7 of the shortlist of an IMO, so it’s not going to be easy at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that for $a=b$ the product $(a^n-1)(b^n-1)$ is square for all $n$. We  prove that this is the only possibility.

Let $b^n=a^n+h_n$; one has $(a^n-1)(a^n-1+h_n)=x_n^2$ so
$$(a^n-1)^2+h_n(a^n-1)-x_n^2=0\Rightarrow 2(a^n-1)=-h_n\pm\sqrt{h_n^2+4x_n^2}$$ so we have a Pythagorean triple
$$(h_n, 2x_n,z_n)=(r_n^2-s_n^2,\space 2r_ns_n,\space r_n^2+s_n^2)$$ and
$$2(a^n-1)=-(r_n^2-s_n^2)\pm(r_n^2+s_n^2)$$ thus for all $n$ $$a^n=s_n^2+1\\b^n=r_n^2+1$$  For $n=2$ we have
$$a^2-s_2^2=1\\b^2-r_2^2=1$$ We are done.

Comment: Can we get $a=b$ using LTE?

Comment: @PNT. Sorry, I don't know what means LTE I am not a native speaker English. What I know is that my solution of this problem is easy and complet: after show that necessarily $a=b$, it follows that $ab$ is trivially square.

Comment: Look at the solution below. It uses the LTE lemma which basically says that the highest power of $p$ that divides $a^n-1$ is the highest power of $p$ that divides $a-1$ + the highest power of $p$ that divides $n$ (assuming $p\mid a-1$)

Comment: @PNT.- Thank you dear friend. I have seen this when I was student. I remember  I was asked about the squares of $\mathbb Q_2$ and I cannot answer so I was deferred in that examination.

Comment: @Piquito I'm excited to see a proof that $a=b$ but I'm having trouble following it.  I don't see any place where we make essential use of the fact that the squareness occurs for all $n$.  It seems to me the argument only relies on $n=2$, but then that stronger claim isn't true since $(2^2-1)(7^2-1) = 12^2$.

Comment: To use the characterization of Pythagorean triples in this way, $h_n$ and $2x_n$ must be coprime. But it’s elementary that $a^n-1$ and $b^n-1$ have the same prime factors for all $n$ (using an LTE argument not unlike PNT’s), and in particular all the prime factors of $x_n$ will divide $h_n$. @ErickWong: see for instance my answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4264555/if-mathrmord-pb-mid-mathrmord-pa-for-all-sufficiently-large-prime-p for an algebraic proof (definitely not elementary), or the shortlist of the 2009 IMO (problem N7) for an elementary argument that $a=b$.

Comment: @Aphelli Thanks for this reference!  I hope you have a chance to post this as an answer, in case this one gets retracted.

Comment: @ErickWong: I don’t think it’s worth posting the linked answer, because the linked answer shows that “$a,b$ have the same order mod every prime” implies $a=b$ ; but this hypothesis, while implied by the problem statement, is rather stronger than “$ab$ is a perfect square”.